# Java not running in crontab

Tags: java, cron

`java -jar /home/scripts/relay.jar` is working fine when I launch from command line. The command produces a file: relay.txt

In crontab

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/oneprovider/relay.jar
```

is not producing anything. I first had it without /usr/bin/ but then did `which java` and added absolute path with no luck. The jar file was originally written for windows but it works in Linux fine when launched from command line

What am I missing?

Comment: can you verify the java process is running when it's supposed to run?

Comment: The command you're executing in crontab is different to the command you execute manually? Why don't you put `java -jar /home/scripts/relay.jar` in your crontab?

Comment: Also, where do you expect the file to be created (and why), and what is the code creating that file?

Comment: @JBNizet when I launch it from command line it creates the file in the same directory where the jar file is. The code is embedded in jar.

Comment: @matt that didn't work, tried it

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions. I asked where you expect the crontab job to create the file (you didn't answer), why you expect that (you didn't answer), and what the code creating the file is (not where the code is).

Comment: @JBNizet I expect the file to be created in the same directory where the jar file resides - same behaviour as executing from command line. It's creating a file with information that is consumed by other processes. I do not have the code, it was written by someone else.

Comment: Then neither you, nor we can explain much. The code matters. My guess is that the code actually creates a file in the *current* directory, and that the current directory of the cron job is not your the directory containing the jar file. To make a car analogy: if I take my car and go 80km to the west, I'll end up in Lyon, France. You doing the same thing from your home will not lead you to the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed that the working directory is likely the problem. Can you write a shell script that wraps the java invocation and sets the working directory?  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cd /home/oneprovider 
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/oneprovider/relay.jar
```

Then change the cron job to run the script instead. Remember to chmod it and make sure that the cron user can write to the directory if it isn't your personal crontab.

Comment: or use /usr/bin/java "-Duser.dir=/home/oneprovider" -jar /home/oneprovider/relay.jar